# Deadlock while trying to call audioProcessStartWithAudioSource:error: in gracenote

Tags: ios, gracenote

I try to create app with possibility to recognize music tracks, however each time I call block:

```
dispatch_async(self.internalQueue, ^{
   self.gnAudioVisualizeAdapter = [[GnAudioVisualizeAdapter alloc] initWithAudioSource:self.gnMic audioVisualizerDelegate:self];
  [self.gnMusicIDStream audioProcessStartWithAudioSource:(id )self.gnAudioVisualizeAdapter error:&musicIDStreamError];
});
```

I get error informing about deadlock

> 2014-10-20 13:29:59.954 BTTest[2193:595084] -[__NSArrayM enqueueObj:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17804f210
>
> 2014-10-20 13:29:59.976 BTTest[2193:595084] *** -[NSCondition lock]: deadlock ( '(null)')
>
> 2014-10-20 13:29:59.977 BTTest[2193:595084] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.

I just Copy&paste several methods from sample sdk into fresh project. Does anybody had similar problem on iOS?

**Edit:**
Ok after few hours of digging I found solution: Add -ObjC into "other linker flags" now no info about deadlock... just "Error: 0xffffffceError: 0xffffd591"

Comment: So you need to add the `-ObjC` linker flag to force the compiler to add the category `NSMutableArray+NSQueue.h`. However, do you still get a deadlock on that line? I have the same issue, where it appears to be deadlocking on `audioProcessStartWithAudioSource`.

Comment: No, after adding this flag all worked as expected. other errors on console was due to wrong audio session management. I was able to fix it quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the edit and comments, the `-ObjC` linker flag is required for the compiler to include the category `NSMutableArray+NSQueue.h`.

The code itself is not deadlocking, but rather the call to `audioProcessStartWithAudioSource::` starts of a loop that is executed synchronously and does not return unless there is an error.

Comment: please read second line logged by system. It clearly states that deadlock is detected and reported.

Comment: That second line occurs after the unrecognized selector causes an exception. Once this was resolved by adding `-ObjC` do you still get that log statement occurring?

Comment: No, after adding flag it disappears. I referred your answer in which you stated that "The code itself is not deadlocking". At this moment this topic is solved.